# I want to search task record on the basis of current week..?

Tags: apex, date

```
Date myDate = Date.today();
Date weekStart = myDate.toStartofWeek();
Date weekend = myDate.toEndofWeek();
lsttask=[select AccountId,priority,status,ActivityDate from task where ActivityDate > weekStart and ActivityDate < weekend ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the examples found [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) on SOQL date formats:

> **Date Literals**
>
> A fieldExpression can use a date literal to compare a range of values
>   to the value in a date or dateTime field. Each literal is a range of
>   time beginning with midnight (12:00:00). To find a value within the
>   range, use =. To find values on either side of the range, use > or <.
>   The following table shows the available list of date literals, the
>   ranges they represent, and examples: Date Literal
>
> **THIS_WEEK** Starts 12:00:00 on the most recent first day of the week
>   before the current day and continues for seven full days. First day of
>   the week is determined by your locale.    **SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE
>   CreatedDate < THIS_WEEK**